# Can't access CouchDB on AWS instance using URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, couchdb

I have installed CouchDB on an AWS Linux instance and can successfully access it via SSH but can't access it using the instance publicly available URL.

In SSH I can run `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/_all_dbs`and it gives me `["_replicator","_users","baseball"]` which is what I am expecting.

If I try to use my AWS instance URL in Chrome: `http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5984/_utils` Chrome says the website refused to connect.

I have edited the CouchDB local.ini file to add CORS. The local.ini now looks like this:

```html
; CouchDB Configuration Settings

; Custom settings should be made in this file. They will override settings
; in default.ini, but unlike changes made to default.ini, this file won't be
; overwritten on server upgrade.

[couchdb]
;max_document_size = 4294967296 ; bytes

[httpd]
enable_cors = true
bind_address = 0.0.0.0

[cors]
origins = *

;port = 5984
;bind_address = 127.0.0.1
; Options for the MochiWeb HTTP server.
;server_options = [{backlog, 128}, {acceptor_pool_size, 16}]
; For more socket options, consult Erlang's module 'inet' man page.
;socket_options = [{recbuf, 262144}, {sndbuf, 262144}, {nodelay, true}]

; Uncomment next line to trigger basic-auth popup on unauthorized requests.
;WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="administrator"

; Uncomment next line to set the configuration modification whitelist. Only
; whitelisted values may be changed via the /_config URLs. To allow the admin
; to change this value over HTTP, remember to include {httpd,config_whitelist}
; itself. Excluding it from the list would require editing this file to update
; the whitelist.
;config_whitelist = [{httpd,config_whitelist}, {log,level}, {etc,etc}]

[query_servers]
;nodejs = /usr/local/bin/couchjs-node /path/to/couchdb/share/server/main.js


[httpd_global_handlers]
;_google = {couch_httpd_proxy, handle_proxy_req, <<"http://www.google.com">>}

[couch_httpd_auth]
; If you set this to true, you should also uncomment the WWW-Authenticate line
; above. If you don't configure a WWW-Authenticate header, CouchDB will send
; Basic realm="server" in order to prevent you getting logged out.
; require_valid_user = false

[log]
;level = debug

[log_level_by_module]
; In this section you can specify any of the four log levels 'none', 'info',
; 'error' or 'debug' on a per-module basis. See src/*/*.erl for various
; modules.
;couch_httpd = error


[os_daemons]
; For any commands listed here, CouchDB will attempt to ensure that
; the process remains alive. Daemons should monitor their environment
; to know when to exit. This can most easily be accomplished by exiting
; when stdin is closed.
;foo = /path/to/command -with args

[daemons]
; enable SSL support by uncommenting the following line and supply the PEM's below.
; the default ssl port CouchDB listens on is 6984
; httpsd = {couch_httpd, start_link, [https]}

[ssl]
;cert_file = /full/path/to/server_cert.pem
;key_file = /full/path/to/server_key.pem
;password = somepassword
; set to true to validate peer certificates
verify_ssl_certificates = false
; Path to file containing PEM encoded CA certificates (trusted
; certificates used for verifying a peer certificate). May be omitted if
; you do not want to verify the peer.
;cacert_file = /full/path/to/cacertf
; The verification fun (optional) if not specified, the default
; verification fun will be used.
;verify_fun = {Module, VerifyFun}
; maximum peer certificate depth
ssl_certificate_max_depth = 1

; To enable Virtual Hosts in CouchDB, add a vhost = path directive. All requests to
; the Virual Host will be redirected to the path. In the example below all requests
; to http://example.com/ are redirected to /database.
; If you run CouchDB on a specific port, include the port number in the vhost:
; example.com:5984 = /database
[vhosts]
;example.com = /database/

[update_notification]
;unique notifier name=/full/path/to/exe -with "cmd line arg"

; To create an admin account uncomment the '[admins]' section below and add a
; line in the format 'username = password'. When you next start CouchDB, it
; will change the password to a hash (so that your passwords don't linger
; around in plain-text files). You can add more admin accounts with more
; 'username = password' lines. Don't forget to restart CouchDB after
; changing this.
[admins]
;admin = mysecretpassword
```

**:UPDATE:**

When running:

```
netstat -a -n | grep 5984
```

I get:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

The `127.0.0.1` but should be `0.0.0.0` as I have set the bindings in both the `etc/couchdb/local.ini` and the `etc/couchdb/default.ini` to be 0.0.0.0.

It looks as if couchdb is picking up it settings from elsewhere? When I run:

```
couchdb -c
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini
/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini
```

When SSHing into the AWS instance the root directory contains two entries:

```
apache-couchdb-1.6.1  apache-couchdb-1.6.1.tar.gz
```

I `cd` to `apache-couchdb-1.6.1` and to edit the ini file do:

```
vim etc/couchdb/local.ini
```

I assume this is the same as the `/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini`?

I have stopped and restarted couchdb and restarted the AWS instance but still couchdb is not picking up the bind_address from the config file(s).

**SORTED IT**

It turns out that `/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini` is not the same as `etc/couchdb/local.ini`. When I put the bindings in the correct ini it all works!

Comment: Did you open port `5984` in the Security Group assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: I added the following to one of the security groups:  

All TCP   TCP   0 - 65535   0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I see you changed the bind address. But you still connect using localhost using ssh. You're not checking the same thing then.

Comment: Not sure what you mean Seva

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only two things required to make it visible outside: you should bind on external ip address (shown as Public IP in EC2 instance properties) and open it on firewall. So it just must be between these two.

I see you changed the bind address to 0.0.0.0. This should address binding step by binding on all interfaces.

But you still connect using localhost using ssh. You're not checking the same thing then. Try to use machine ip address instead of 127.0.0.1 when trying to test with curl. It should be the one shown as as Public IP in EC2 instance properties. But if in doubt, use `ifconfig -a` to figure out what ip addresses you have. You can also check on what interfaces it actually bound by running following command  `netstat -a -n | grep 5984`. It must show 0.0.0.0:5984 (or *:5984) as LISTEN (not 127.0.0.1:5984). Otherwise it's not binding on correct port and you should check CouchDb configuration file to see why. It also pays to check that CouchDB is really using the config you're editing.

On the firewall side - check that you have open it on the correct security group. It must be the one shown in "Security groups" property of your EC2 instance and the rule you open must be inbound.

Some times instance firewall jumps in and cause troubles too. But I only had this issue on Windows machines. I believe it is disabled on AWS Linux machines (at least I never needed to adjust anything there - Security group rules were always enough).

If this still doesn't work. I can only suggest trying to test it with telnet whether it connects at all. As browsers sometimes misreport exact stage to make it simpler for an average user. Connecting with telnet is a more low level test, but keep in mind you need to separate port with a space for telnet instead of a colon, e.g. `telnet 1.2.3.4 5984` where 1.2.3.4 is server's ip address.

Comment: I have sorted it! I was editing the wrong copy of the ini file (see my updated question). I wouldn't have got this far without your help so if you would like to amend your answer to include the right path for the ini file then I will award you the reward. Many thanks for your help and perseverance!

Comment: @Bill Sorry, I wasn't checking stackoverflow for few days. I did clean up the answer a bit to include important details from the discussion which I believe helped to point you in right direction. But I believe your edit to the question is way much better then anything I can come up with. So, I believe you should be able to edit my answer if you want to do so. But I would rather keep it as it is as I feel like any edit would only make it harder for a potential reader later to figure out what the issue was.